# ClassNotFoundException for Tomcat org.apache.catalina.Authenticator

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to use a valve from IBM for role based authentication into Tomcat 9 using HTML headers passed from IBM Secure Access Manager (Tivoli Access Manager). I have configured the valve within the Engine Block as shown below:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" >
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase" />
    </Realm>

    <!-- Here is my valve declaration -->
    <Valve className="com.ibm.tivoli.integration.am.catalina.valves.AMTomcatValve"
           debugTrace="true" addRoles="myrolename" groupsHeader="iv-groups" />

    <Host name="localhost" appBase="/path/to/WARs" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" >
        <Valve classname="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
               directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b />
    </Host>
</Engine>
```

However, this causes Tomcat to fail to start. Here is the Stacktrace:

```
Server start FAILED
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.Authenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 35 more
```

I am not sure what is causing this error as the class org.apache.catalina.Authenticator clearly exists within my catalina.jar located within my `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory. I have placed my AMTomcatValve.jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib and added it to the classpath that is given to the java command that starts up tomcat.

Also the Tomcat image starts when the valve tag is removed. It also starts when the valve is moved outside of the engine block (this removes it from the context however), but I am met with an "Unexpected Authentication Error" when trying to get into my app using the IBM Security Access Manger WebSeal.

Are there any suggestions on how to get Tomcat to find this class? I'd really like to avoid writing a custom login/authentication valve

Comment: Can your Tomcat start if the valve tag is removed?

Comment: Where is your `com.ibm.tivoli.integration.am.catalina.valves.AMTomcatValve` class located?

Comment: I have placed it into `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` and added it to the classpath that is given to the `java` command that starts up tomcat

Comment: Also to answer Kohei's question, yes the Tomcat image starts when the valve tag is removed. It also starts when the valve is moved outside of the engine block (thus removing the context), but I am met with an "Unexpected Authentication Error" when trying to get into my app using the IBM Security Access Manger WebSeal

Comment: @willh99 Did you have any luck with Tomcat 9?
According to [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-security-access-manager-apache-tomcat), this is only supported until Tomcat 8 but I am in the same boat as yours and would really be interested in knowing what you ended up with.